# git for multiple linux users

Tags: linux, git, commit

I have a specific question about the git file, "COMMIT_EDITMSG". I have a setup where three linux users have access to the same repository. The repository was initialized with the following commands:

```
git init --shared=group
chgrp -R GROUP-NAME .git
```

Where GROUP-NAME is the group including all the users who are to work with the repo. Now, USER1 creates a new files and commits it.

```
echo 'hello' > hello.txt
git commit -a
```

After that, a COMMIT_EDITMSG file is created in the .git folder. This file was created by default with permissions "644", belonging to USER1:GROUP-NAME. This is bad because when USER2 or USER3 tries to add files and then commit them, he doesn't have permissions to edit this file, which is required for committing.

What I did was simply change the file's permissions to "664", but I have a feeling that if I'm needing to mess with the permissions, then I am not properly using git. Is there something "improper" about the way I'm doing thing here?

Thanks...

Comment: Why not giving each user its own clone of the repository to work with?

Comment: I would underline that: Have a central "blessed" repo at exactly the location it currently is, and have every user clone from there, push back, and work on their own in a separate repository. This is the whole point when using GIT: Decentralized version control.

Comment: @michas - Yes, we want each person to have a clone on their local computer, but we also want to make sure they can push to the directory themselves, and not have to make a pull request.